# plugin to set selection start cursor in Firefox without holding mouse button?

Tags: firefox, user-interface, firefox-addon

when selecting large swaths of text from webpage I have to keep left mouse button pressed while searching for the selection's end. It would be nice if the browser would "remember" selection's start point and let me search for the ending point, e.g. by dragging the scrollbar downwards, without pressing the mouse button.

Does a plugin or other implementation of this sort already exist?

Comment: Check this out, you can find the index of the selection, start and end: [MDN :: Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FSelection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is OS/Windowing system specific. In most/all systems there is a normal way to have the system perform what you are desiring. An add-on for Firefox is not required.

**Windows:**
If you click (button down and up, not button down and hold) at the start, or the end of the selection you desire then move the mouse to the other end of the desired selection (scrolling the page as needed to get the the other end) you can then hold the shift key down and click again. This will select the entire region from the first point you clicked to the second point you clicked while holding the shift key.  You can adjust the selection by continuing to hold the shift key while doing any of: clicking on a different location, performing a click-drag movement, or using the keyboard cursor keys. This adjustment does not change the point at which you first clicked, just the second, end point.

It is also possible to use the control key to select individual items.  This is possible in combination with clicks, double-clicks, and triple-clicks.  An example would be to move your mouse around in this paragraph holding the ctrl key down while double-clicking on various words.  Your selection will include just the words on which you double-clicked.  In some instances, when using only a single ctrl-click to select from a discrete list (e.g. a Windows Explorer folder display), a second ctrl-click on the same item will de-select it. You can also combine the use of ctrl-click and shift-click to create more complex selections with the beginning of the shift-click selection starting at the most recent ctrl-click location.

The [Mouse and Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742466.aspx) page in the Windows Dev Center provides some fairly technical descriptions as guidelines for Windows developers.

**Linux (using GNOME):**
The interactions are similar to What was described for Windows, but a bit different. Section [10.1.2. Selecting Objects](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/unstable/input-mouse.html.en#selection) of the [GNOME Human Interface Guidelines 2.2.3](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/unstable/index.html.en) provides a good description.

**Apple/OSX:**
The [Macintosh Human Interface Guidelines](http://dropbox.scripting.com/dave/misc/appleHumanInterfaceGuidelines.pdf) describes how selections can be made on Apple machines.

Comment: What about this Mayken? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FSelection

Comment: doing it without Shift would have been nicer, e.g. allowing for searching in page with CTRL F, but this is better than nothing.